# Webcrypto wrapKey hash padding with RSA OAEP

Tags: encryption, hash, openssl, cryptography, webcrypto-api

I am able to generate an AES key,and along with my OpenSSL generated public key I have imported,wrap it with code like:

```
    window.crypto.subtle.wrapKey(
        'raw',
        sharedKey,
        publicKey,
        {
            name: 'RSA-OAEP',
            hash: {name: "SHA-1"}//I can change this to SHA-256 or any valid hash function
        }
    ).then(function(encryptedSharedKey) {
        resolve(encryptedSharedKey);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        reject(err);
    });
```

My question is, regarding OpenSSL RSA OAEP keys, it seems like it always uses SHA-1 for padding. It seems like no matter what hash I specify in the webCrypto wrapKey function, I am still able to decrypt the encryptedSharedKey with my OpenSSL private key with a command like

```
 openssl pkeyutl -decrypt -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:oaep -inkey myprivatekey -in sessionKey.enc
```

Is there a bug where webcrypto is not actually changing the hash type when I wrap the keys, or do I misunderstand how the hash plays a factor?

Comment: It looks to me like the hash is indicated in the wrapper, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_encapsulation.  Can you do a hex dump or a data inspection of the output of wrapKey?

Comment: @JawguyChooser RSA-KEM != RSA-OAEP

Comment: Derek, this could well be a bug...

Comment: Yeah, I have played around with it a little bit more, but between the absolute mess that is OpenSSL documentation, and the sparseness of this, it is hard for me to convince myself that i've tried everything and done it right.